# Position three buttons on the same centre line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three separate buttons within the same row and container, however due to the content above them, they're not all on the same horizontal line.

[image: Current]

This is worsened on a big screen

How can I get all these buttons sitting on the same centre point?

**Live URL:** http://185.123.97.138/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**HTML**

```
<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffa68f2-f144-418b-afe0-4de05390e083" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
```

Comment: just remove this `#step1button` for first button. it have `margin-top`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D although I completely agree. Surely the issue being highlighted in this instance is very specific to this use-case, so the odds of it being useful to someone else in the future are exceptionally low.

Comment: Too localised used to be a close reason too...just saying.

Comment: I see your point but, it no longer is a reason. Not to mention, if it were still in place, it would alienate a lot of users by limiting what they could ask and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using a seperate row was that on a mobile device all the three buttons (in the seperate row) sat away from their relevant content.

This meant it was very confusing on a mobile device to understand what the buttons took the user to, this looked like:

[image: Odd mobile]

By adding a simple `<br />` I was able to push the one odd button onto the same line as the other two buttons.

I then removed:

```
              #step1button {
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

So the final HTML looked like:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
<div class="fadein bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
         <div class="box-content">
                       <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
                       <figure><img src="/img/pound-coins.jpg" alt="saving money image" title="Saving money" class="tripleimage">
                       <figcaption><b>Feel like you're walking on a tightrope every day?</b> <br>Stuck in a pay cheque to pay cheque cycle, can't keep your budget in check, dont have a budget, use credit cards or have no savings? <br><br>
                        <br />
                       <b>Lesson 1</b> - Learn how I escaped the pay cheque to pay cheque cycle.</figcaption>

                       </figure>


<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffa68f2-f144-418b-afe0-4de05390e083" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>


              </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't predict the text in the above sections will always finish at the same point so, as they currently are, it's not technically possible. There are some hacky fixes you could do, but I think the best solution would be to take the buttons out of those containers entirely, and have a separate "row" element that contains them.

That way, if the text in one of the columns gets longer for whatever reason (text added, different screen sizes), the whole "button row" will be pushed down equally and the buttons will always maintain the same baseline

Hope that makes sense

Comment: he could also change that row with those elements to be a flex display, couldn't he?

Comment: Yes, but doing so would pretty much eliminate IE from displaying it correctly due to flex-box not being that widely supported. Of course, a polyfill library could be used. But display as simple as that really shouldn't depend on JS

Comment: I suppose. I don't tend to care too much about IE since it's basically not standards compliant.

Comment: It's actually very standards compliant, the problem is that it doesn't get updated, like other browsers, when the standard changes. But considering the global usage is apparently ~5%, I wouldn't be too concerned about it. Especially considering the majority of that is probably mandatory usage due to it being the browser enforced on employees by lots of businesses. Ultimately, flex or not, your mark-up will most likely have to change to achieve what you're after. Let me know how it goes

Comment: The problem with this approach is that on a mobile device the buttons then sit separate from the relevant content. In fact all three buttons sit together below all three div's. I found a simple solution.

Comment: True, but you could place a copy of each button with the text it relates to, and use media queries to hide the row and show the duplicates. That way, if the text above any of the buttons changes, the baseline will still be maintained and they will be next to the content they relate to in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Modify the line in homepagestyle.css

```
#step1button {
    margin-top: 21px;
}
```

This will fix your issue

Comment: Your solution will only work at a particular screen-width. I'm viewing it on 1920x1080 and it doesn't address the issue at all. Snapping the window to one side, resulting in 960px width, makes the issue worse

Comment: In that case he should write the button code outside the div. At least i think that could be easier to handle it.

Comment: Refer to my answer

Comment: Oops sorry. I haven't seen your answer. @Ryuu

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your contribution :)