# Order row buttons on mobile below appropriate column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with three seperate columns and a seperate button for each of these columns in a new row.

This works fine on desktop but on mobile it stacks all the buttons together below all the columns so it's confusing which button relates to what.

**Currently:**

[image: Current version]

**What I'd like:**

[image: What I'd like]

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
<div class="fadein bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
         <div class="box-content">
                       <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
                       <figure><img src="/img/pound-coins.jpg" alt="saving money image" title="Saving money" class="tripleimage">
                       <figcaption><b>Feel like you're walking on a tightrope every day?</b> <br>Stuck in a pay cheque to pay cheque cycle, can't keep your budget in check, dont have a budget, use credit cards or have no savings? <br><br>

                       <b>Lesson 1</b> - Learn how I escaped the pay cheque to pay cheque cycle.</figcaption>

                       </figure>  
              </div>
              </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 columnBorder"> 

       <img src="/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
       <div class="box-content column-border">
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
           <figure>
             <img src="/img/saving-to-buy-a-home.jpg" alt="Buying a house" title="Saving to buy a house" class="tripleimage"><figcaption><b>Is saving for a house causing you anxiety?</b> Stressed out over a correction or rise in interest rates?<br><br>
Worried if you don't buy now house prices will continue to rise and out price you?<br><br>
             <b>Lesson 2</b> - Tips to rapidly save for your future home.
             </figcaption>
             </figure>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
       <div class="box-content">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Want</b> to make more money?</p>
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/going-travelling.jpg" alt="How to make more money" title="How to make more money"  class="tripleimage">
        <figcaption><b>Want to increase your income?</b>
       <br>Want to drive a better car, go travelling or live in a better neighbourhood? Increase your income to scale up your savings and substantially improve your current lifestyle. 

        <br><br><b>Lesson 3</b> - It's not just about being frugal. How to easily increase your income without taking large risks.
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row text-center"">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffa68f2-f144-418b-afe0-4de05390e083" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffe5fc5-349c-41f9-acf4-085a82c7f0b9" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="d2faa459-edd3-4c4a-9e34-997a2bfc4f21" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Live link:** http://185.123.97.138/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/index2.html

**Notes:** I'm using Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is just add the buttons in to each grid "`col-sm-4`" as follows,rather than adding separate row and creating yet another three grids,

```
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
       <div class="box-content">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Want</b> to make more money?</p>
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/going-travelling.jpg" alt="How to make more money" title="How to make more money"  class="tripleimage">
        <figcaption><b>Want to increase your income?</b>
       <br>Want to drive a better car, go travelling or live in a better neighbourhood? Increase your income to scale up your savings and substantially improve your current lifestyle. 

        <br><br><b>Lesson 3</b> - It's not just about being frugal. How to easily increase your income without taking large risks.
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
         <button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffe5fc5-349c-41f9-acf4-085a82c7f0b9" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
        </div>
```

So the code should have to be,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
<div class="fadein bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
         <div class="box-content">
                       <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
                       <figure><img src="/img/pound-coins.jpg" alt="saving money image" title="Saving money" class="tripleimage">
                       <figcaption><b>Feel like you're walking on a tightrope every day?</b> <br>Stuck in a pay cheque to pay cheque cycle, can't keep your budget in check, dont have a budget, use credit cards or have no savings? <br><br>

                       <b>Lesson 1</b> - Learn how I escaped the pay cheque to pay cheque cycle.</figcaption>

                       </figure>  
           <button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffe5fc5-349c-41f9-acf4-085a82c7f0b9" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
</div>
              </div>
              </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 columnBorder"> 

       <img src="/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
       <div class="box-content column-border">
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
           <figure>
             <img src="/img/saving-to-buy-a-home.jpg" alt="Buying a house" title="Saving to buy a house" class="tripleimage"><figcaption><b>Is saving for a house causing you anxiety?</b> Stressed out over a correction or rise in interest rates?<br><br>
Worried if you don't buy now house prices will continue to rise and out price you?<br><br>
             <b>Lesson 2</b> - Tips to rapidly save for your future home.
             </figcaption>
             </figure>
         <button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="d2faa459-edd3-4c4a-9e34-997a2bfc4f21" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1" class="middleimages">
       <div class="box-content">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Want</b> to make more money?</p>
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/going-travelling.jpg" alt="How to make more money" title="How to make more money"  class="tripleimage">
        <figcaption><b>Want to increase your income?</b>
       <br>Want to drive a better car, go travelling or live in a better neighbourhood? Increase your income to scale up your savings and substantially improve your current lifestyle. 

        <br><br><b>Lesson 3</b> - It's not just about being frugal. How to easily increase your income without taking large risks.
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
         <button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="6ffe5fc5-349c-41f9-acf4-085a82c7f0b9" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-middle">Start Class Now</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row text-center">

</div>
</div>  
</div
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue here is that because the content above the buttons varies in length the buttons sit at odd positions (when placed in the same row). I had asked a previous stack question around this, as previously took this approach but got slammed for not using a separate row. I'm really at a loss now?

Comment: See: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/ where I have used this approach but the buttons sit at odd levels (best demonstrated on a large screen).

Comment: I found a solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515002/position-three-buttons-on-the-same-centre-line/36545032#36545032

Comment: @SamJefferies Okay, great (Y)